# Elasticity tensor for non-isotropic materials

Tags: metric-tensor, elasticity

How are the components of the elasticity tensor $C_{ijkl}$ defined for ANY material, especially those that are not isotropic? Does it always depend on the metric tensor (which in orthonormal Cartesian coordinates would equate to Kronecker's deltas)?

Can you give theoretical values or estimations? How would you get/conceive them? And how would you measure all $C_{ijkl}$ components by observation?